# XPath expression with condition on multiple ancestors

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

The application I am developing receives an XML structure similar to following:

```
<Root>
    <Valid>
        <Child name="Child1" />
        <Container>
            <Child name="Child2" />
        </Container>
        <Container>
            <Container>
                <Child name="Child3"/>
                <Child name="Child4"/>
            </Container>
        </Container>
        <Wrapper>
            <Child name="Child5" />
        </Wrapper>
        <Wrapper>
            <Container>
                <Child name="Child19" />
            </Container>
        </Wrapper>
        <Container>
            <Wrapper>
                <Child name="Child6" />
            </Wrapper>
        </Container>
        <Container>
            <Wrapper>
                <Container>
                    <Child name="Child20" />
                </Container>
            </Wrapper>
        </Container>
    </Valid>
    <Invalid>
        <Child name="Child7" />
        <Container>
            <Child name="Child8" />
        </Container>
        <Container>
            <Container>
                <Child name="Child9"/>
                <Child name="Child10"/>
            </Container>
        </Container>
        <Wrapper>
            <Child name="Child11" />
        </Wrapper>
        <Container>
            <Wrapper>
                <Child name="Child12" />
            </Wrapper>
        </Container>
    </Invalid>
</Root>
```

I need to get a list of of Child elements under following conditions:

1. **Child** is **n** generation descendant of **Valid** ancestor.
2. **Child** may be **m** generation descendant of **Container** ancestor which is **o** generation descendant of **Valid** ancestor.
3. Valid ancestors for **Child** element are **Container** elements as **m** generation ancestors and **Valid** element as first generation ancestor.

where m, n, o are natural numbers.

I need to write following XPath expressions

```
Valid/Child
Valid/Container/Child
Valid/Container/Container/Child
Valid/Container/Container/Container/Child
...
```

as a **single** XPath expression.

For provided example, the XPath expression would return only **Child** elements having **name** attribute equal to **Child1**, **Child2**, **Child3** and **Child4**.

The closest I have come to solution is following expression.

```
Valid/Child | Valid//*[self::Container]/Child
```

However, this would select **Child** element with **name** attribute equal to **Child19** and **Child20**.

Does XPath syntax supports either optional occurrence of an element or setting condition similar to self in previous example to all ancestors between **Child** and **Valid** elements?

Comment: Interesting one. +1. I can recall only a simple union like `Valid/Child | Valid/Container/Child | Valid/Container/Container/Child`. May be @Alejandro or @Dimite will provide an easy way to skip only `Container` steps.

Comment: @Flack +1. That really covers the provided example. However, the number of **Container** elements between **Valid** and **Child** elements is arbitrary (0,1,2,3,...)

Comment: I hope @Dimitre has the solution.

Comment: @Rest Wing, also this suffice for your example: `Valid//Child[not(ancestor::Wrapper)]`

Comment: @Flack: +1. Yes, it would suffice for this example. However, there might be an arbitrary number of such "invalid" ancestors. Therefore, I need a more general expression, something like `Valid//Child[each ancestor after Valid::Container)]`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest and simplest so far solution, which may well be also the most efficient. :)

Comment: @Rest Wing: I think you should rephrase the question to make last part of it more significant and to match more directly @Dimitre good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//Child[ancestor::*
          [not(self::Container)][1]
                            [self::Valid]
       ]
```

**When this XPath expression is evaluated on the provided XML document:**

```
<Root>
    <Valid>
        <Child name="Child1" />
        <Container>
            <Child name="Child2" />
        </Container>
        <Container>
            <Container>
                <Child name="Child3"/>
                <Child name="Child4"/>
            </Container>
        </Container>
        <Wrapper>
            <Child name="Child5" />
        </Wrapper>
        <Wrapper>
            <Container>
                <Child name="Child19" />
            </Container>
        </Wrapper>
        <Container>
            <Wrapper>
                <Child name="Child6" />
            </Wrapper>
        </Container>
        <Container>
            <Wrapper>
                <Container>
                    <Child name="Child20" />
                </Container>
            </Wrapper>
        </Container>
    </Valid>
    <Invalid>
        <Child name="Child7" />
        <Container>
            <Child name="Child8" />
        </Container>
        <Container>
            <Container>
                <Child name="Child9"/>
                <Child name="Child10"/>
            </Container>
        </Container>
        <Wrapper>
            <Child name="Child11" />
        </Wrapper>
        <Container>
            <Wrapper>
                <Child name="Child12" />
            </Wrapper>
        </Container>
    </Invalid>
</Root>
```

**Exactly the wanted nodes are selected:**

```
<Child name="Child1"/>
<Child name="Child2"/>
<Child name="Child3"/>
<Child name="Child4"/>
```

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
//Child[ancestor::*
          [not(self::Container)][1]
                            [self::Valid]
       ]
```

**means**:

From all `Child` elements in the document, select only those, for which the first ancestor that is not a `Container` is `Valid`.

Comment: @Dimitre: +1. Magnificent, simplicity achieved. Too bad I cannot give more than one up-vote :)

Comment: Using this answer I was able to easily tackle nested `Valid` elements as well by `and`-ing the current condition with `count(ancestor::Valid) = 1`.

Comment: @RestWing: Yes XPath is an amazing language. Not even to mention XPath 2.0 and XPath 3.0. Recently I implemented the Binary Search Tree data structure entirely in XPath 3.0 -- have a look at this in my blog.

Comment: @Dimitre: Will do. I suppose .NET framework supports only XPath 1.0, correct?

Comment: @RestWing: Correct. However there are at least two .NET XSLT 2.0 processors: Saxon and XQSharp and both of these, of course, support XPath 2.0. Saxon EE9.3.04 (paid version) has an early implementation of XPath 3.0 and XSLT 3.0.

Comment: +1 For paying more attention. I didn't see that last definition of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Valid
 //Child[count(ancestor::Container[ancestor::Valid])
          = count(ancestor::*[ancestor::Valid])]
```

Explanation:

```
//Valid//Child
```

Returns all `Child` nodes that are descendants of `Valid` nodes.

```
count(ancestor::Container[ancestor::Valid]])
```

Returns the number of `Container` tags that are ancestors of the current node (`Child`) and themselves have an ancestor called `Valid`

```
count(ancestor::*[ancestor::Valid])
```

Returns the number of all tags that are ancestors of the current node (`Child`) and themselves have an ancestor called `Valid`

Therefore two values are only equal if all tags between `Valid` and `Child` are called `Container`.

However, this expression assumes that there won't be any nested `Valid` tags, i.e. `/Valid/Valid/Child` will not be accepted by it.

**Update:** Looking at your xml one more time, wouldn't this be easier?

```
//Valid//Child[not(ancestor::Wrapper)]
```

Comment: +1. Splendid. The expression from the update would probably be easier. However, it is less strict than the first one. See the question comment regarding the answer proposed by Flack. I can suppose there will not be **Valid** element nesting :)

Comment: Although your solution works, I have marked the solution given by @Dimitre as the final answer. However, I am not taking off your stripes, you have deserved them :)